# Input and output restricted deque

Tags: algorithm, math, discrete-mathematics, knuth

How to prove that the number of permutations of an increasing sequence using an input restricted deque is equal to number of permutations using output restricted deque? In Knuth's 'The Art of Computer Programming' it is given that there is one to one mapping between an input restricted permutation say x and 'rev of inverse of reverse of x' and the latter can be obtained with ORD. How to prove that it can be obtained with ORD?